# usbguard rules allow any keyboard and mouse

Tags: usbguard

here is an `/etc/usbguard/rules.conf` file, that was generated via `usbguard generate-policy > /etc/usbguard/rules.conf`

This is on a Dell optiplex pc, having just a wired keyboard and wired mouse connected, **RHEL-8.9** and `usbguard-1.0.0-13.el8.x86_64`

```
allow id 1d6b:0002 serial "0000:00:1d.0" name "EHCI Host Controller" hash "WHBTxNaEoMGNSNc31KpFNSAeFF4HbLMQgSBqORlC6S8=" parent-hash "jW2YTPWRLeQOE7Q8I2f0pdN13zFYXVQGQoNmr1gDZgg=" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type ""
allow id 1d6b:0002 serial "0000:00:14.0" name "xHCI Host Controller" hash "jEP/6WzviqdJ5VSeTUY8PatCNBKeaREvo2OqdplND/o=" parent-hash "rV9bfLq7c2eA4tYjVjwO4bxhm+y6GgZpl9J60L0fBkY=" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type ""
allow id 1d6b:0002 serial "0000:00:1a.0" name "EHCI Host Controller" hash "ej1WVedyLyUMLiQxzEcrwbY45zCodwV85Kzy7hm2Gv4=" parent-hash "e/RW0mMbM+TSFQxpRiMEfL7/3RJfKVdqffBm9F5qA+E=" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type ""
allow id 1d6b:0003 serial "0000:00:14.0" name "xHCI Host Controller" hash "3Wo3XWDgen1hD5xM3PSNl3P98kLp1RUTgGQ5HSxtf8k=" parent-hash "rV9bfLq7c2eA4tYjVjwO4bxhm+y6GgZpl9J60L0fBkY=" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type ""
allow id 8087:0024 serial "" name "" hash "Zx7v0FMQEjScKSAFENAiobEs1OGPPB0YWR+yXDCVE04=" parent-hash "WHBTxNaEoMGNSNc31KpFNSAeFF4HbLMQgSBqORlC6S8=" via-port "1-1" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type "hardwired"

allow id 0461:4d51 serial "" name "DELL Laser Mouse" hash "w2bwgTsGy6TVhOOr7smHrvF8PtmYVKQwxbqgA5betmI=" parent-hash "jEP/6WzviqdJ5VSeTUY8PatCNBKeaREvo2OqdplND/o=" via-port "2-3" with-interface 03:01:02 with-connect-type "hotplug"
allow id 413c:2003 serial "" name "Dell USB Keyboard" hash "3eEGsGE566EIofQwRf06EINoPRynZIa/09c3uyy4TTY=" parent-hash "jEP/6WzviqdJ5VSeTUY8PatCNBKeaREvo2OqdplND/o=" via-port "2-4" with-interface 03:01:01 with-connect-type "hotplug"

allow id 8087:0024 serial "" name "" hash "kv3v2+rnq9QvYI3/HbJ1EV9vdujZ0aVCQ/CGBYIkEB0=" parent-hash "ej1WVedyLyUMLiQxzEcrwbY45zCodwV85Kzy7hm2Gv4=" via-port "3-1" with-interface 09:00:00 with-connect-type "hardwired"

allow id 0461:4d22 serial "" name "USB Optical Mouse" hash "OZ6XJQmjdeDg7Dp2MelZt+ewNTtdNTt92FtGPI0VPAc=" parent-hash "kv3v2+rnq9QvYI3/HbJ1EV9vdujZ0aVCQ/CGBYIkEB0=" via-port "3-1.4" with-interface 03:01:02 with-connect-type "hotplug"
```

Without having that last line in the rules file, that second mouse will not work when plugged in, so I know as this rules file is written that it is specific to keyboards and mice.

My question is - and I have been told this is possible - how do you write the rule syntax to allow any keyboard and any mouse connected [to any usb port] of a system ?

Bonus question: if a wired usb kybd and mouse is plugged into a monitor having usb ports, then you have one usb cable from that monitor to the computer usb port, can that be whitelisted to allow any monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated rules aren’t specific to keyboards and mice, they’re specific to the devices that were connected to the system when they were generated.

To allow any keyboard and mouse, use [a rule matching those](https://usbguard.github.io/documentation/rule-language.html):

```
allow with-interface one-of { 03:00:01 03:01:01 03:00:02 03:01:02 }
```

In each colon-separated triplet, the first value is the interface class, the second is the interface subclass, and the third is the interface protocol. Class 3 is “Human Interface Device”. Specifying both subclasses 0 and 1 allows boot and non-boot devices to match. Protocol 1 is keyboards, protocol 2 is mice.

The documentation shows a fancier variant which only allows the first keyboard:

```
allow with-interface one-of { 03:00:01 03:01:01 } if !allowed-matches(with-interface one-of { 03:00:01 03:01:01 })
```

This can be adapted for mice by changing the protocol to 2.

As far as monitors are concerned, the relevant feature is their hubs in most cases; that’s interface class 9:

```
allow with-interface equals { 09:*:* }
```

Comment: I am using just this one line in `/etc/usbguard/rules.conf` with success : `allow with-interface one-of { 03:*:* 09:*:*}`