# usbguard rules - interface class, subclass, protocol listing

Tags: usb, usbguard

in relation to this question: [usbguard rules allow any keyboard and mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769390/usbguard-rules-allow-any-keyboard-and-mouse/769417#769417)

from https://usbguard.github.io/documentation/rule-language.html it mentions

> interface-type represents a USB interface and should be formatted as three 8-bit numbers in hexadecimal base delimited by colon, i.e. cc:ss:pp. The numbers represent the **interface class** (cc), **subclass** (ss) and **protocol** (pp) as assigned by the USB-IF (List of assigned classes, subclasses and protocols).

right now in my usbguard rules file to allow any keyboard or mouse I am doing

```
allow with-interface one-of { 03:00:01 03:01:01 03:00:02 03:01:02 }
```

- I am interested to know if there is a complete description of `cc:ss:pp`; I was able to find https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes and I assume assuming their *base class* means *interface class* ?

  - is there some listing of *sub-class* and *protocol* somewhere ?

in Linux (RHEL 8.9) if I just plug some usb device in as a test how can I get that sort of information (rather than doing a `usbguard generate-policy > newrules.txt` again to find out) ?

right now a `lsusb` shows this below, this is on a simple dell optiplex pc running RHEL 8.9 having twoDell usb kybd two Dell usb mouse connected

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. KB212-B Quiet Key Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard SK-8115
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

*so `lsusb` is not giving me interface class given the keyboards, bus/device here is not synonomous with interface_class ?*